# Show that $V$ is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we let

$$V = \{ x \mid x = \begin{bmatrix}
       x_1           \\[0.3em]
       x_2
\end{bmatrix},\text{ where }x_2 > 0 \} $$

and define addition and scalar multiplication by

$$u + v = \begin{bmatrix}
       u_1           \\[0.3em]
       u_2
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
       v_1           \\[0.3em]
       v_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       u_1 + v_1           \\[0.3em]
       u_2 v_2
\end{bmatrix} $$

$$cu = \begin{bmatrix}
       cu_1           \\[0.3em]
       u^c_2
\end{bmatrix} $$

The first thing that I would normally do when proving subspaces is check if the zero vector is in $V$. In this case that doesn't seem feasible since $x_2$ is restricted to numbers greater than zero. How can I show the zero vector is in $V$ and go on to show that vector addition and scalar multiplication is closed?

Comment: Think of $x_2$ as $e^y$ then you'll see the parallel features between this $V$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "zero vector" in this vector space is the vector $(0,1)$.
Note that $(u,v) + (0,1) = (u+0, v\times 1) = (u, v)$.

Comment: So because vector addition is not defined normally we have to also modify what it means for our "zero vector" to be in V?

Comment: The point is that the vector $(0,0)$ is NOT always the "zero vector" that satisfies the vector space axioms for a particular vector space.

Comment: Okay, cool. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: The zero vector is the one that when added to another vector yields just that other vector.  Your definition of "addition" has consequences.

Answer (score 1):

In this space the zero vector is of the form:

\begin{bmatrix}
       0           \\[0.3em]
       1            \\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}